# not able to run jquery - ajax with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**Welcome.php**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#role").on("change", function() {
      alert($("#role").val());
      var role_name = $("#role").val();

      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "createuser.php",
        data: "role_name=" + role_name,
        success: function(data) {
          $("#info").html(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

I'm trying to run jquery - ajax in php file but the code is not working secondly only first alert() function is working. When `alert()` is used within `$ajax()` function both the `alert()` stops working

Comment: Can you update alert($("#role").val()); with alert($(this).val()); and check

Comment: You're code looks fine, what does firebug (or something else) tell you?

Comment: Please see console of your browser to see actual error.

Comment: most likely you don't know where the js console is

Comment: @Naruto code doesn't look fine.

Comment: You are not passing data correctly. Try this  `data:{"role_name":role_name},`

Comment: First of all the alert can only be used inside the success function

Comment: `var role_name  = $('form').serialize();` try that?

Comment: a post request data seems not well done

Comment: It give following error in js console:  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).$ is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (welcome.php:20)
    at j (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2)

Comment: do you mind posting the html form and a snippet from createuser.php @JasshhAndrews

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile - <?php
#fetching table for selected role by admin

if(isset($_POST['role_name']))
{
 echo $_POST['role_name'];
}


?>

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile HTML - echo " <h4 class='w3-text-indigo'>Admin please select role to download documents.</h4> 
       <select id='role' name='role_name[]' class='w3-input w3-light-grey' style='width:90%'>"
                                 . "<option value='select Role'>Select Role</option>";
                           
       while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
       {
        $role_name = $row["Role_name"];
        echo  "<option  value=$role_name>".$role_name."</option>";
       }

Comment: I'm getting this error in js console window -  $("#role").$(document).on("change",function(){

Answer (score 0):

`Jquery AJAX post` data should be in JSON format so for you something like:

```
var Sdata = {"role_name":role_name};
$.ajax(
     {                       
       type:"post",
       url:"createuser.php",
       data: Sdata,
       success:function(data){
       $("#info").html(data);
     }
});
```

[More about JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be json

Comment: Well it should be. Its the prefered way to send data with AJAX jquery according to the docs

Comment: You're actually passing a plain object to jQuery, declared using JSON-style notation. You could just as easily declare it as follows: var obj = new Object(); obj.role_name = 'role'; 

jQuery accepts arrays and strings as data too. Nowhere in the documentation (that I can see) does it explicitly recommend that plain objects declared using JSON be used over the alternatives. Stating that JSON format is the recommended way to do it is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

This does work on my side, I made the role select box static, because I don't have the data from the database.(well thats not really the case here)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#role").on("change",function(){

               var role_name = $(this).val();

               $.ajax(
               {                       
                   type:"post",
                   url:"createuser.php",
                   data:"role_name="+role_name,
                   datatype : 'json',
                   encode : true,
                   success:function(data){
                      data = JSON.parse(data) ;
                      $("#info").html(data);

                   }

               });

         });
    });

</script>  
<div id="info"></div>
<form method="POST">
    <h4 class='w3-text-indigo'>Admin please select role to download documents.</h4>
    <select id='role' name='role_name[]' class='w3-input w3-light-grey' style='width:90%'>" . "
    <option value='select Role'>Select Role</option>
    "; 
    <option value="User">user</option>
    <option value="Tester">Tester</option>
    <option value="Developer">Dev</option>
    <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
</form>
```

then the php site

```
<?php #fetching table for selected role by admin 



if (isset($_POST['role_name'])) {
    echo json_encode($_POST['role_name']);
}
?>
```

Comment: code got worked thanks for your effort but stupid thing i did was i did not closed the select tag echo "</select></div>". That is the reason my data was not getting printed.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this data:{"role_name:"+role_name} instead of data:"role_name="+role_name,